# VIM Android IDE

Tags: java, android, linux, vim

Подскажите плагины с помощью которых можно полноценно разрабатывать android приложения

Comment: вы спрашиваете про VIM или про IDE для Android. Вы используете Android Studio или другую среду? уточните вопрос, больше подробностей, сейчас не понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: И желательно уточнить, что означает "полноценно разрабатывать".

Comment: https://github.com/hsanson/vim-android

Comment: https://spacevim.org/use-vim-as-a-java-ide/